# EF SQL query Performance on comma-separated string Ids

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq, entity-framework-core

To store and query on associated IDs, which method works best in terms of query speed and performance? Especially in a large number of records in primary table, such as 100,000 records.

1- Use the comma-separated string field as Ids :

```
query.Where(x => (',' + x.Ids + ',').Contains(',' + value + ','));
```

2- Use a separate table and join operation :

```
query.Where(x => x.SecondaryTable.Any(s => s.Id == value));
```

Comment: *which method works best* - is this not just a case of trying each?

Comment: Sure you could test this and find out, no?

Comment: **var query = db.PrimaryTable.AsQueryable();**

Comment: Second for sure. First  is full table scan.

Comment: Fast method is to use one of the command line utilities that comes with SSMS (also built into Power Shell).  I like using SQLCMD.EXE.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The correct way to model this in a relational database is to use a separate table for the values (your option 2 in the question).

Comment: `Use the comma-separated string field as Ids` - please do not do this. this should be on a list called `top 10 worst things to do with databases`

Comment: I'd expect the second to be faster, but as others have alluded to the only real way to find out is to [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store Ids as comma separated string - you always have TABLE/INDEX scan. If your table is small it can be enough.

With `SecondaryTable` table which stores Ids associated with main table there a lot of other plans:

1. You can leave as is and trust or not DB Engine optimiser

```cs
query = query.Where(x => x.SecondaryTable.Any(s => s.Id == value));
```

2. If pair (MainId, Id) is unique. The following query should definitely hit index

```cs
var query = 
   from m in query
   from s in m.SecondaryTable.Where(s => s.Id == value)
   select s;
```

3. If pair (MainId, Id) is NOT unique.

```cs
var secondary = db.SecondaryTable.Where(s => s.Id == value);
var mainIds = secondary.Select(s => new { s.MainId }).Distinct();

query = 
   from m in query
   from s in mainIds.Where(s => s.MainId == m.Id)
   select m;
```

Anyway, better to test and check execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

The first option performs a string comparison on a dynamically-generated string, so there is no possibility of an index improving query performance.  It will be exceptionally slow.

The second option is performing a numeric comparison on an indexed primary key (assuming that Id is some numeric type and that it is the primary key).  This is a much faster comparison for your processor to evaluate, and it is a simple comparison without generating dynamic data for said comparison.